# How to encrypt software securely?

Tags: c#, encryption

I have software I wish to encrypt for protection. I currently protect my software this way:

1. Compare HDD and CPU serials with stored ones (I store them encrypted
   in program user settings)
2. All data stored in DB encrypted by DES. DES key and IV I store in
   windows registry.

I understand that this level of protection is weak and storing key and IV in registry is not a good idea. Please give me some advice to improve this protection.

Comment: Keep it in a cupboard.

Comment: `I protect my software this way:`  Before you start blindly applying encryption to various aspects of your application you need to first do create a threat model and then go from there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model

Comment: You are shipping a list of other user's serials in the app?  You need to create some sort of key and send it back. You also need to define the registration process.  Is there an online server?  WIll you manually do stuff?  [this might be interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34686620/1070452)  You might also want to just subscribe to a service to do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use DES, it is not secure and has been superseded decades ago by AES.
2. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see  [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Use CBC mode with an IV, see 3 below.
3. The IV should be a random string generated for each encryption, prepend it to the encrypted data for use during decryption—it does not need to be secret.